# Salesforce formula for End of string

Tags: salesforce, formula

I have some salesforce roles following the format:

- `developer_team_london`
- `developer_team_paris`
- `developer_team_madrid`

I need to create a formula field named `Team` that takes only what's after the substring `team`, so in this case the result will be `london` (`paris`, `madrid`).

How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ways to do it, depends on data, how likely it is to change. What have you tried?

```
SUBSTITUTE(LastName, 'developer_team_', '')
MID(LastName, LEN('developer_team_') + 1, 99)
MID(LastName, FIND('team_', LastName) + LEN('team_'), 99)
```

[image]